# How to reference a specific chapter in a book in Bookdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I know it is possible to include references to specific sections/chapters of citations in Latex, but am wondering if there is a way to do this within the R Bookdown environment. Searches show lots of ways to reference other sections of the book I am writing in bookdown. For context, including a bookdown citation such as [@Gelman2014] produces the following reference in the pdf output: (Gelman 2014). I am looking for a way to get something along the lines of (Gelman 2014 Sec 2.1). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO, @lcaruso!

You could try something like this:

```
[@Gelman2014 \text{Sec} 2.1]
```